# TypeError `[ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]`: On NodeJs

Tags: node.js, express, fs

Received undefined throw new `ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK(cb);`

```
const fs = require("fs");
const text = "File ";

fs.writeFile("node-message.txt", text)
  .then(() => {
    console.log("File Created");
  })
  .catch(() => {
    console.log("File not created");
  });
```

I am getting this TypeError `[ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]`: Callback must be a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to require an `fs module` with promises if you are facing an invalid callback type error.

```
    const fs = require("fs").promises;
    const text = "File ";
    
    fs.writeFile("node-message.txt", text)
      .then(() => {
        console.log("File Created");
      })
      .catch(() => {
        console.log("File not created");
      });
```